# Custom menu for mobile version of Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile

I have App Script for my Google Sheet in this Sheet I have custom menu , all works good but it doesn't work in mobile version ( for phone) can you help my, any solution please

I tried make button , and hyperlink but nothing don't work for me , I need or clickable button for implement my function or any other solution, now I do it from custom menu( I call my needed function but it doesn't work in mobile version

Answer (score 1):

**A Way to run functions on a mobile**

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") { 
    e.source.toast("Gate");
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    executeFunctionByName1(e.range.offset(0,1).getValue())
  }
}

function one() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange(2,3,1,2).setValues([["I am one",new Date()]])
}

function two() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange(3,3,1,2).setValues([["I am two",new Date()]])
}

function executeFunctionByName1(func) {
  this[func]();
}
```

Image of Sheet0:

[image]

> Just click on a checkbox and it will run the name of the function on the same row in column B.

Demo:

[image]

> You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need tp perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet.

**Sample onEdit event object**

```
 function onMyEdit(e){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))};
//{""authMode"":""FULL"",""oldValue"":""10.0"",""range"":{""columnEnd"":6,""columnStart"":6,""rowEnd"":6,""rowStart"":6},""source"":{},""triggerUid"":"""",""user"":{""email"":"""",""nickname"":""""},""value"":""pp""}
```

Comment: `onMyEdit` → `onEdit`, or run through harness